# Why is Rails 4.2.1 looking for index.html in production (apache2, passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, passenger, apache2.2

I have the following software stack deployed on production:
Rails 4.2.1
Apache 2
Passenger 5.0.13

This is the error on production.log when requesting the application via browser:

> [2015-07-12T17:22:23.089940 #5378]  INFO -- : Started GET
>   "/index.html" for 10.0.0.89 at 2015-07-12 17:22:23 +0000 F,
>   [2015-07-12T17:22:23.090858 #5378] FATAL -- : 
>   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/index.html"):
>   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
>
>   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
>   railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'   railties
>   (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call'   activesupport
>   (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
>
>   activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`
>   tagged'   activesupport (4.2.1)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'   railties (4.2.1)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call'   actionpack (4.2.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'   rack
>   (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in`call'   rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'   activesupport (4.2.1)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in`
>   call'   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'   railties
>   (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in`call'   railties (4.2.1)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
>
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/passenger-5.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:94:in`
>   process_request'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/passenger-5.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:149:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
>
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/passenger-5.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in`main_loop'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/passenger-5.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:415:in
>   `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
>
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/passenger-5.0.13/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:111:in`block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'

My config/routes.rb is as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   root 'sessions#new'
   # - Session Resources - #
   resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
   resources :password_resets
end
```

In development the root page is served accordingly, but in production a blank screen with the above errors.

Please assist.

Comment: do you have .htaccess file, if yes, what is it's content?

Comment: You are sure you have deployed the latest updates to your server, correct?  Any chance it may have failed to deploy and you are trying to route to an index.html that doesn't exist?

Comment: I dont have .htaccess file anyway within the configuration.

Comment: @mike Yes, I did deploy the application via capistrano3.4.0 and no errors were thrown.

Comment: Check 'RAILS_ENV=production rake routes' against 'RAILS_ENV=development rake routes' it's probably something missing in a config file.